# Handle null values on database or application?

Tags: java, database, model-view-controller

Have a pretty newbie question. Where should null values be handled so that they are not visable to the end user. Lets say you have some properties and those properties have an OPENDATE. Some of the values for OPENDATE in the database may currently be null. From an application standpoint I would render an empty string in this particular instance to the end user. Would you handle this with the query, or on the application side lets say you have a java web app?

db:

```
SELECT NVL(TO_CHAR(OPENDATE), ' ') from table
```

or

java:

```
if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("null")
//render empty string
```

Comment: It depends. I would ask why am i getting null in application and what makes my field null in DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should handle it in your View layer* (e.g. JSP)

Your business logic (domain objects) should contain NULL values if that is to represent that "the value has not been set".

Displaying an empty string to the user is specific to the display device and context.

*The *View Layer* could also mean your View controller logic where you prepare the backing beans that will be used to display your data on the JSP.

What's important is that you can tell the difference between a NULL value (value not set) and an Empty String (value has been set, but it's a blank string) when you need to. For example, you may wish to toggle the HTML display of some data element if a user has not set a value.

To address your question specifically, it probably doesn't make sense for a `Date` field to have the value of a blank `String` in your [Domain Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_model). A good rule of thumb is to keep your data correctly `Typed` for as long as possible in your program flow (i.e. your [Value objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object)).

Answer (score 1):

Generally any changes to visual appearance of an application are handled application-side(your java code). It is cleaner this way and provides an easier way to debug your code. This way, when you program starts looking weird out of nowhere, you'll know the only changes to appearance are all in one spot and you don't have to mess around with your SQL queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it anywhere. I would say in your java code.

```
if (str == null) {
   str = "";
}
```

You can also use [wasNull()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#wasNull()) provided by `ResultSet`

```
str = rs.getString("column")
if(rs.wasNull()) {
  str = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer provided by grice, but I would go further and say that in your domain model you should explicitly make it clear this field may not be present.  Using a null, like anywhere, can cause other problems so make your field an Optional.  In Java 8 you can use the built-in, prior to that you can use [Guava's Optional](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained)